Cannot connect Azure DB for PostgreSQL from Dataflow in ADF
I want to insert data into and update a table in Azure DB for PostgreSQL using Data flow in ADF. But I cannot create connection between data flow and DB due to a network error.
Because of company policy, only private connections are available on the Azure network.
And the connection with SHIR is not allowed in dataflow so I tried to create the link service of Azure DB for PostgreSQL with managed private endpoint. But that connection failed.

The error message was
The value of the property '' is invalid: 'The remote name could not be resolved: '***.postgres.database.azure.com''.
The remote name could not be resolved: '***.postgres.database.azure.com'

What is the cause? I am concerned that the Managed Private Endpoint is "Provisioning". But I could not find the page to approve it.

I have no idea whether what I did was correct so any answer would be helped.
What I want to do is to connect DB from dataflow using private network.
Thank you.

please check the solution and let me know if I can help you more.

To connect the Azure Postgres database with private access from Azure Data Factory You need to use Azure Private Link service to create a private endpoint for Postgres SQL.

First you need to create a subnet under your virtual network for load balancer, private link service and backend server.
After that create load balancer and private link service connected to each other.
create backend server to connect properly on the network.
Now using that private link service, you can create and connect private endpoint on it  and use it to connect Azure Postgres database with private access,

How to access Azure PostgreSQL Flex Server from ADF Managed VNet using a Private End Point this document given by @Omer Ahmad has step by step process.
